# I want to find first day and any other in a month in SQL query 

Tags: sql

I want to find first day month of month and also like 3rd day or 5th day ,15th day or any day of the  month .So how to find through query.I know how to find first day and last day of month.Mainy I want find other days.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server have a look here http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/18/sql-server-find-last-day-of-any-month-current-previous-next/ and then follow Andriy's post.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you following along who may not know how to get the First Day of the month in SQL Server you can do so with something like this. This will also give you the 5th, 10th or whatever you need.

```
DECLARE @FirstDay DATETIME
SET @FirstDay = (DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) - 1, -1) + 1)

SELECT  GETDATE() AS CurrentDay
        , @FirstDay AS FirstDay
        , DATEADD(d, 10, @FirstDay-1) AS TenthDay
```

The -1 after the @FirstDay in the DateAdd is because the DateAdd will add the numbers of days onto the firstday, which will give you the 11th in that example. Of course you could just add one less day to make it work without the -1 but I prefer including it. Suit yourself.

Comment: `DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) - 1` is essentially equivalent to `DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())`, isn't it? In fact, all the calculation could be simplified to `DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)`. Anyway, your method is working. Other than that, adding the actual number of days to `@FirstDay-1`, though equivalent to how I suggested, seems a better idea (more logical, I think).

Comment: I like your simplification more then then one I used.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to find the first day of a month, you can add the 2-day, the 4-day or the 14-day interval to the first day of the month to get, respectively, the 3rd, the 5th or the 15th day of the month.

Similarly you can get any day of the month by simply adding the proper number of days.

Different RDBMSs may offer different syntax to achieve the goal. Assuming `@MonthBeginning` to be a `date` or `datetime` value representing the first day of a month, here's how you can get, for example, the 5th day of the same month in Microsoft SQL Server:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, 4, @MonthBeginning) AS FifthDay
```

Again, it may not be the way you should do that if your RDBMS is not MS SQL Server.